# Graph Theory:Folkman Graph

Tags: graph-theory

I want to prove that Folkman graph is edge transitive but not vertex transitive, and I don't know how can I start to prove, any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What is the Folkman graph?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folkman_graph#/media/File:Folkman_graph.svg                                                                              I mean this

Comment: A good start would be to give a definition/construction of Folkman's graph that will allow to describe its automorphism group. Unless you are happy with a proof involving Sage math :)

Comment: This is not an easy problem. If Jernej's suggestion does not suit you, your best starting point might be the original paper by Folkman.

Comment: @Chris Godsil  & #Jernej tnx for your help :)